# Multiple conditions in an If else statement c program

Tags: c

My program is supposed to basically determine the type of triangle based on the length of the sides that the user inputs.
I'm getting this error message for my code which tests to see if it's a scalene triangle

> expected ';' before '{' 
>   else((right != left) || (right != bottom) || (left != bottom)){

Code:

```
else((right != left) || (right != bottom) || (left != bottom)){
                printf("This is a scalene triangle");
            }
```

The error is saying to put a ; right after the last condition, which doesn't make sense to me. I tried doing so to test it out but it gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: Did you mean to put `else if` instead of just `else`?

Comment: Can you put a larger portion of your code ? (mostly code before)

Comment: I understand the problem and it's been solved, would you still like to see a larger portion of my code though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming this is supposed to be an `if...else` in which case you need an extra `if` after the `else`...

```
else if ((right != left) || (right != bottom) || (left != bottom))
{
    printf("This is a scalene triangle");
}
```

---

In response to the OP's comments...

> From the notes i were reading the format was the last statement of the else if just being else, hence why I didn't use else if and just used else

The notes are correct, to a point - in that the last statement **can** be an `else` statement (and if you have an `else` it must be the last statement and there can only be one).

So the following is valid...

```
if (a == 1) {
   // Do this
} else {
   // Do that
}
```

But the following is **not** valid...

```
if (a == 1) {
   // Do this
} else {
   // Do that
} else {
   // Do other
}
```

The `else if` allow you to continue the logic processing over multiple blocks... which can finish with an `else` block if required...

```
if (a == 1) {
   // Do this
} else if (b == 1) {
   // Do that
} else {
   // Do other
}
```

Or not...

```
if (a == 1) {
   // Do this
} else if (b == 1) {
   // Do that
} else if (c == 1) {
   // Do other
}
```

Comment: Thank you. From the notes i were reading the format was the last statement of the else if just being else, hence why I didn't use else if and just used else. I changed it and it worked

Comment: Sounds like the notes are correct... the last one **can** be just `else`, but `else if` allows you to have multiple condition-based blocks, so you can have `if ... else if... else if... else if... else`

Comment: @David1083 - I hope my edit makes thing a bit clearer for you.  Please don't forget to mark the answer you found the most useful, so others know your issue is solved (plus you get some useful reputation on the site)

Answer (score 1):

`else` cannot have a condition statement, it is supposed to be `else if` if condition check need to be included.

It must be changed as below

```
else if ((right != left) || (right != bottom) || (left != bottom)){
                printf("This is a scalene triangle");
            }
```